# Code-First Unique Index Constraint Prevents Any Insertions after Inserting a Duplicate

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, unique-index

Here's an entity's property:

[image]

I try to enforce uniqueness by specifying a unique single-column index, and it works **until after** a duplicate value is inserted. When a duplicate insertion occurs, the database throws an exception, as it is supposed to. Then, further attempts to insert **any** value lead to the same constraint being triggered, and a rebuild is required.

This only happens when .SaveChanges() is called. I've tried inserting rows manually into the table, and everything works.

Am I missing something, or is this a known bug in EF?

Comment: Hard to say without the code. Just a note: if there are multiple entries that are modified/added to the DbSet of the same DbContext, and SaveChanges is called, they all will be saved. You might want to take a look at the ChangeTracker of the DbContext and check how many entities are added/modified. This may lead you to the root problem.

Comment: Dispose the context after using it.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for that. I had to detach the the entity from the context in the catch block, and it solved my problem.

Comment: I consider that a work-around to the real issue: a long-lived context.